# Python WebScraping with BeautifulSoup. Issue 'tuple' object has no attribute 'h1' and 'p'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuXEY.png)

Hello I'm having a bit of an issue with web scraping this URL I have been writing it in my code editor but also doing it in cmd as i go along to make sure i getting it right. I have hit a issue which says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'h1'
```

I have also done 'p' as well to see if it could maybe get a paragraph off the page but that did not worth either.Please check the above issue.

Thanks for you help

Comment: First you should post your code in this question instead of an image.  For larger issues we cannot help without copy-pasting to figure out what's wrong when the code is run.  For your case I would replace the problem line with `page_soup[0].h1` since it is the first object in your tuple that actually has header data

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
page_soup = (uClient.read(), "html.parser")
```

to:

```
page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
```

It creates BeautifulSoup object.